# When to use `form:` in Typed Racket?

Tags: annotations, racket, legacy, typed-racket

[ts-guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/more.html#%28part._.Annotating_.Definitions%29) said:

> In addition to the `:` form, almost all binding forms from racket have counterparts which allow the specification of types.

But it does not say when to use which one.

And [ts-reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Legacy_Forms.html) said `form:` is legacy, for backwards compatibility.

But in ts-guide, `form:` are used in a lot of places.

So is `: v t` preferred than `form:`?
And what about `form`?

For example:

```
; form:
(define: (id [z : Number]) : Number z)

; : v t + form
(: id (-> Number Number))
(define (id z) z)

; form (it seems recent versions of Racket add this?)
(define (id [z : Number]) : Number z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Form

The first form uses the special form `define:`. It and other forms ending with `:` are [legacy forms](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Legacy_Forms.html?q=define%3A#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._define~3a%29%29) in the current version of Racket  (*v 6.1.1* at the time of this answer). It is equivalent to `typed/racket`'s `define` but does not accept the second form. It is  available for backward compatibility.

### Second Form

The second form more closely reflects the idea of a *function signature* as described in the process for [designing functions](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3adesign-func%29) in the book [How to Design Programs*](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/index.html). Even better, because `typed/racket` allows writing

```
(: id (Number . -> . Number)
```

using the [reader's infix macro](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-accept-infix-dot%29%29) we can get a much closer correspondence to *How to Design Programs* at the price of a few extra characters.

### Third Form

The third form is more traditional in terms of statically typed languages...by which I mean it maps more closely to the C language, Java, ML, etc. It is also more general because it can be used in anonymous functions:

```
> ((lambda ((x : Number)) : Number (+ x 10)) 4)
- : Number
14
```

### Remarks on Type Inference

Note that `typed/racket` has type inference and it was not necessary to specify the return type as in:

```
> ((lambda ((x : Number))(+ x 10)) 4)
- : Number
14
```

Indeed `typed/racket` will always do it's best to infer types if none are specified:

```
> ((lambda (x)(+ x 10)) 4)
- : Integer [more precisely: Positive-Index]
14
> ((lambda (x)(+ x 10)) 4.0)
- : Flonum [more precisely: Positive-Flonum]
14.0
> ((lambda (x)(+ x 10)) 4/1)
- : Integer [more precisely: Positive-Index]
14
```

### Conclusion

Of course, what `typed/racket` infers may not be what the programmer expects. Using the second form has the advantage of making the programmer's intent explicit and making the programmer's intent explicit is a core principle of *How to Design Programs* and at the heart of the motivations for developing `typed/racket` in the first place.

Comment: "It is identical to typed/racket's define ..." It seems `define:` is not identical to `define`. `define:` enforces the third form, e.g. `(: id (-> Number Number)) (define: (id x) x)` gives this error: "define:: expected more terms starting with the literal symbol `:'"

Comment: @weakish I had written "equivalent" in an earlier draft and changed it to the stronger term. I have reverted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> But it does not say when to use which one.

In most cases they are equivalent.

I like the second form - it makes it easy to remove the TR annotations again.

Comment: For `define` I prefer the second too. But what is the second form for `struct`?

Comment: I don't think there is one.